# Having trouble when replacing in a list-Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am having trouble replacing lists on python, my code is below.

```
def words_open():
    global words
    wordsfile = open("words.txt","r")
    words_list = wordsfile.readlines()
    words = []
    for i in range(len(words_list)):
        words.append(words_list[i].strip())
    return words_list
    return words 

def replace_symbol_for_letter(letter,symbol):
    print([s.replace(symbol,letter) for s in words])
    return words

def enter_pairing():
    correct_symbol = False
    while correct_symbol == False:
        symbol = input("Please enter a symbol: ")
        if symbol not in symbols_list:
            correct_symbol = False
        elif symbol in symbols_list:
            correct_symbol = True
    correct_letter = False
    while correct_letter == False:
        letter = input("Please enter a letter: ")
        letter = letter.upper()
        if letter not in alphabet:
            correct_letter = False
        elif letter in alphabet:
            correct_letter = True
    current_pairings.append(symbol and letter)
    replace_symbol_for_letter(letter,symbol)
    return letter
    return symbol
```

The code runs fine, without syntax errors, however I am having trouble replacing the 'words' list. 
When I run the code this happens:

```
The words are: 
#+/084&"

#3*#%#+

8%203:

,1$&

!-*%

.#7&33&

#*#71%

&-&641'2

#))85

9&330*

Please enter a symbol: #
Please enter a letter: A
['A+/084&"', 'A3*A%A+', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.A7&33&', 'A*A71%', "&-&641'2", 'A))85',              '9&330*']
Please enter a symbol: +
Please enter a letter: b
['#B/084&"', '#3*#%#B', '8%203:', ',1$&', '!-*%', '.#7&33&', '#*#71%', "&-&641'2", '#))85', '9&330*']
```

As you can see the symbol is replaced to the letter, which works fine, however as soon as I enter a new symbol/letter pairing it deletes the previous replacement and the replaces it again.

Thanks!

Comment: You should fix your indentation first.

Comment: `replace_symbol_for_letter` returns the original, unchanged `words`. This would be much easier if you used a dictionary `{'#': 'A', ...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you don't modify the `words` list in `replace_symbol_for_letter`

```
print([s.replace(symbol,letter) for s in words])
```

This does not modify words list it just creates a new list having the pairing changed but `words` does not change
Replace it by this:

```
words = [s.replace(symbol,letter) for s in words]
print words
```

This should make it.

By the way: global vars are evil :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately I have a problem now, I am not sure whether you wrote that for python 2.x-I am using python 3.3.5. I get the following message:                     `words = [s.replace(symbol,letter) for s in words]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
`

Comment: `words` should be a list of strings, but apparently you provide a list of lists. Check the code generating the words list. In the snippet above, if indentation is right you return the wrong variable in `words_open` function. drop the line `return words_list`.

Comment: Hi I have ammended the code for the lists to work properly, however when I use words = [s.replace(symbol,letter) for s in words] I get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'words' referenced before assignment

Comment: Either you declare `words` to be global, either you give words in the function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your file avec reading it, you should consider to use the `with` statement to open your file, it will close it automaticly after your actions on it.

```
def words_open():
    with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
        words_list = file.readlines()

    words = [line.split() for line in words_list]
    return words_list, words
```